# How i can refresh this function on started value

Tags: reactjs

> Hi! i have a problem with my state in React, I have two onMouse functions, the first one is to add an element and the second one is to delete, unfortunately the second one does not delete and the added element 'opacity' is rendered.

```
    let menuItems = ['Tasks', 'Issues', 'Files', 'Raports']
    const [item, setItem] = useState(menuItems)
    const handleSpace = (id) => {
        menuItems.splice(id, 0, 'opacity')
        setItem([...item])
    }
    const restart = () => {
        menuItems = ['Tasks', 'Issues', 'Files', 'Raports']
        setItem([...item])
    }

    return (
        <>
            <div className="dashboard" style={slide.flag ? {left: '-105%'} : {left: '0%'}}>
                <div className="dashboard__nav">
                    <ul className="dashboard__nav-list">
                        {item.map((item, id) => {
                            return <li className="dashboard__nav-item" key={id} onMouseOver={() => handleSpace(id)} onMouseLeave={restart}>{item}</li>
                        })}
                    </ul>
                </div>
                <div className="dashboard__array">
                    {tasks.map((task, id) => {
                    return (
                        <div className="dashboard__array-item" key={id}>
                            <div className="dashboard__array-item-header">
                                <p className="dashboard__array-item-header-title">{task}</p>                           
                                <button className="dashboard__array-item-header-cancel">
                                    <FontAwesomeIcon icon={faCancel} />    
                                </button>  
                            </div>
                            <div className="dashboard__array-item-main">
                                <p className="dashboard__array-item-main-description">{descriptionTasks[id]}</p>
                                <p className="dashboard__array-item-main-button">Show More</p>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    )
                    })}
                </div>
            </div>
        </>
    )
```

I already created setItem(menuItems), it removed the element 'opacity, but juz it didn't add it a second time

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that the two functions might be over complicating the handling of the `item` state.

Try handle `setItem` without changing another variable `menuItems`, so it can be used as a reset value at anytime.

Example:

```
const menuItems = ["Tasks", "Issues", "Files", "Raports"];

const [item, setItem] = useState(menuItems);

const handleSpace = (id) =>
  setItem((prev) => {
    const newItems = [...prev];
    newItems.splice(id, 0, "opacity");
    return newItems;
  });

const restart = () => setItem(menuItems);
```

Hope this will help.